# Re entry to US after 10 year ban expired

Tags: customs-and-immigration, visa-refusals, visa-bans, north-america

I voluntarily left the US in 2006 after having overstayed for 3 years. I moved to America as a teenager and lived with my Aunt and cousins. Completed high school and decided to move back to Europe. Tried to visit again a couple years later and received a ban at the embassy. The ban has expired and I want to apply again as my cousin is getting married this year. What are my chances of being accepted and how can I reassure them at the embassy that I am not interested in living in America? I'm married myself, have lived in the UK for 12 years with a good job.
Would appreciate your insight on this!

Comment: You were banned. The ban has expired, but your chances of getting a visa are still not good. If you want to improve your chances find a lawyer with experience in US immigration to help you. Without professional help I would expect that you won't  get a visa.

Comment: We have no data to tell you about changes you may get, so answers risk to be opinions (so against the rules). Personally, I think you will get the visa: circumstances completely changed. Being marries, and having a good job help, and after a certain age, who want to stay again to aunts? Just document enough that you have good reason to leave US, and do not hide or downplay the overstay.

Comment: I’m no expert but I tend to agree with Giacomo Catenazzi. Ten years is a long time, you were young when you breached Immigration rules, a lot has changed in your personal circumstances since then. Assuming you’re not planning to make a long visit, and you can show credible and compelling reasons to demonstrate no immigrant intent (eg property ownership in the UK, to add to the ties you mention in your question).

Comment: If you left immediately after high school, there should not have been any ban. Overstays don't tally until you turn 18. Perhaps you forgot to mention the overstay as a minor in your previous application? That would be worse than the overstay itself, as it might suggest errors and omissions in your current application.

Comment: Hi. That's interesting. I turned 19 on my graduation day. I didn't omit my age on the application. I was even questioned about it during my interview. Her biggest issue was the fact that I decided to "leave my parents at such a young age". It didn't make sense to her and she banned me because she thought I lied about the whole story. In my culture it is the norm for other relatives to help raise your child which I tried to explain to her but fell on deaf ears.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your contribution. I tried to book an appointment with the embassy yesterday but on their website there are no available dates. I refreshed the page numerous times to no avail.